# My teacher accidentally put one of the codes on my test and I used it

Tags: exams, code

On my programming midterm, my teacher gave me one of the codes for the question on accident. I did not mention this to the teacher and used it as my answer and deleted where he gave it to me. The reason I did this was because, each student had to answer 10 out of 13 of the questions and I answered exactly 10. So if I were to go ahead and tell him during the test he would have told me I was not allowed to answer it. However, I was not as confident in the other two options so just hoped he wouldn't notice. Now I understand that I am at fault for using the code. However, my professor took off all the points for that question. This is the part that I do not see is fair. He is at fault for giving me the code but again it is my fault for using it. I do think a more fair approach was to do just grade the test as if that question was not there. Being that it is also his responsibility to check the test beforehand. Do you think this is fair or should he have just taken the question off my test.

Also forgot to mention everyone had a different test and was taking it at different so the other student who take the same test as me was not with me while I was taking it.

What appropriate options do I have?

Comment: It sounds like you cheated on a test and are not happy with the consequences. Is it moral to steal from someone's house if they left their door unlocked? I don't think anyone on this site can help you with that situation.

Comment: What's your question? Is it _Do you think this is fair or should he have just taken the question off my test._?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a rant without an actionable question.

Comment: @RichardErickson, I added what seems to be the obvious question. I think it is within the OPs intent. But, yes, I didn't notice that when I answered.

Comment: How he "accidentally" gave you the code is unclear, how could you have deleted it?

Comment: Wht precisely is meant by "code"? On what does this code have to do with the solution to the question in the test?

Comment: @JochenGlueck, programming computer code. Probably in an electronically transmitted test that was editable.

Comment: @BryanKrause "Is it moral to steal from someone's house if they left their door unlocked?" yes without any doubts! It's *their* door, the goods *inside* are their goods. The part about the morality is "was the thief stealing out of need?" and whether he broke or not a lock is not moral, it is just a technicality...

Comment: OP, if it was finance, you took some risk, using the code, aiming at the big rewards of a perfect score 10/10. 
Your bet did not pay out, but the risk turned out to be minimal, lucky you.

Answer (score 2):

If the professor gave you the code as part of the exam then there was no fault in using it. However, removing it without comment, was deceit. Had you not done that then there would be no basis for any complaint against you.

I can't say your professor was wrong in denying points, nor do I know exactly why he did so. But it would be worthwhile, for a lot of reasons, to ask for a meeting with him to see if there can be a happier resolution than losing all the points. Don't complain that he is unfair, but explain what happened, even admitting that you removed the code he included.

But deceit in any form is an offense.

Answer (score 0):

> I do think a more fair approach was to do just grade the test as if
> that question was not there

You are absolutely **right**, one should **always** judge with the maximum objectivity other people fairness avoiding to bring his/her own bias.

In fact I do think a more fair approach was you to notify the teacher, and you answer one of the other questions, instead of the one with the code.